# Need to persist value selected in dropdownlist in MVC View Using Angular

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4

I am new to both MVC and AngularJs so please excuse me if this is a stupid question.  I have a dropdownlist in an Asp.net MVC View that is populated using AngularJs.  When the user selects a Company in the dropdown list, I use the companyId to populate an unordered list.  My problem, I need to use that same selected CompanyID in another controller and C# method.  I have found some info on saving data in a service to reuse it, but I'm not sure if that is what I really need here (or if there is a simpler way to do it than creating a service), but if it is, I don't know how to save the value in a service.

Here is my View code:

{{company.vchCompanyName}}
        
        
        
        Current Dashboard Modules:

  {{m.vchRankingWidgetModuleHeaderText}}

```
Here is my Angular Controller code:

    myApp.controller("CompanyController", 
    function($scope, $timeout, companyService)
    {
        getCompanies();
        function getCompanies() {
            companyService.getCompanies()
                .success(function (data) {
                    $scope.companies = data;
                })
             .error(function (error) {
                 $scope.status = 'Unable to load customer data: ' + error.message;
             });
        };


        $scope.getCurrentModules = function(){
            companyId = $scope.company;
            companyService.getCurrentModules(companyId)
            .success(function (newdata){
                $scope.currentModules = newdata;
            });

        }

    });
```

Here is my Angular Service:

```
angular.module('dashboardManagement')
       .service('companyService', ['$http', function ($http) {
    this.getCompanies = function () {
        return $http.get('/Home/GetAllCompanies');
    };

    this.getCurrentModules = function (id) {
        return $http.get('/Home/GetCurrentModules?companyId=' + id);
    };
}
```

]);

Any assistance is greatly appreciated!

I tried using the Service but I cannot get it to work.  I need to show Business Units for a company if the Business Units checkbox is checked.  I put the function "getBusinessUnits" on the ng-checked and tried to use the service to retrieve the CompanyID.  My View looks like this:

```
            <div ng-controller="BusinessUnitsController">
            <input id="ckBusinessUnit" type="checkbox" ng-checked="getBusinessUnits()"/>Exclude by Business Units<br />
            <ul>
                <li ng-repeat="unit in businessUnits">{{unit.Description}}</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

My Controller looks like this:

```
myApp.controller("BusinessUnitsController",
    function ($scope, $timeout, companyService) {
        $scope.getBusinessUnits = function () {
            companyId = companyService.selectedCompanyId;

            companyService.getBusinessUnits(companyId)
                .success(function (data) {
                    $scope.businessUnits = data;
                 });
        };
    });
```

The code in the Service is exactly as you suggested:

```
   angular.module('dashboardManagement')
.service('companyService', [
    '$http', function ($http) {

        this.selectedCompanyId = null;

        this.getCompanies = function () {
            return $http.get('/Home/GetAllCompanies');
        };

        this.getCurrentModules = function (companyId) {
            this.selectedCompanyId = companyId;
            return $http.get('/Home/GetCurrentModules?companyId=' + companyId);

        };

        this.getBusinessUnits = function (companyId) {
            return $http.get('/Home/GetBusinessUnits?companyId=' + companyId);
        }
    }
]);
```

I'm obviously missing something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CompanyService can be used to stock a selectedCompanyId as a property.

```
angular.module('dashboardManagement')
       .service('companyService', ['$http', function ($http) {

    this.selectedCompanyId = null;

    this.getCompanies = function () {
        return $http.get('/Home/GetAllCompanies');
    };

    this.getCurrentModules = function (companyId) {
        this.selectedCompanyId = companyId;
        return $http.get('/Home/GetCurrentModules?companyId=' + companyId);
    };
}]);
```

Then you can access the selectedCompanyId everywhere in your others controller/directive by injecting companyService.

Note that it is like a Singleton with a single instance, so you can have only one selected company for your whole angular application.

Comment: Just to be sure that I understand how to use it...If I need to access it in another controller, I would call it like this: "companyService.selectedCompanyId"?

Comment: I'm trying to use the service as suggested but it is not working (of course I'm doing something wrong).  I'm trying to call the selectedCompanyId in another controller like this: myApp.controller("BusinessUnitsController",
    function ($scope, $timeout, companyService) {
        $scope.getBusinessUnits = function () {
            companyId = companyService.selectedCompanyId;

            companyService.getBusinessUnits(companyId)
                .success(function (data) {
                    $scope.businessUnits = data;
    I'm using the code you posted above in the service.

Comment: That should work, you get the main principle. What error/unexpected value do you have? Can you provide a fiddle that show the problem?

Answer (score 0):

if I understand well you need to save the select companyId in your View and then pass it to your controller(c#) right?

try this, add a new property in your angularjs controller

```
       $scope.SelectedCompanyId = '';
```

then in your dropdownlist add this attribute

```
     ng-model="SelectedCompanyId"
```

then add a new hidden input

```
 <input type="hidden" name="CompanyId" value="{{SelectedCompanyId}}" />
```

now if in the model that are you using in your view have a property CompanyId, when you do the post back it will map the value, or just in your controller add a new parameter

```
     [HttpPost]
     public ActionResult YourActionName(YourModel model, int? CompanyId)
     {
         //you can access to the CompanyId
         //int? CompanyId --> this is only if your model doesn't have a property called CompanyId

     }
```

Comment: Your suggestion sounds like a viable approach, but there is no Model on the view, that is, if you are referring to @Model, otherwise, I'm not sure what you mean.  Thanks for taking the time to help.

Comment: if the view doesn't have a model, just in your controller use the int? CompanyId

   [HttpPost]
     public ActionResult YourActionName(int? CompanyId)
     {


     }